# How to use apache thrift C# TMemoryBuffer at client and server end with thrift 0.9.3?

Tags: c#, thrift

It seems that `TMemoryBuffer` is one kind of `Transport` in `thrift`. But it cannot be used with any server (`TThreadedServer`, `THreadPoolServer`, `TSimpleServer`) since `TMemoryBuffer` is not derived from `TServerTransport` which is required by all these server. I did not find any useful document about how to use it.

Is there any example or document somewhere?

Comment: You can use `TMemoryBuffer` to serialize data into an `byte[]` array, and vice versa. That's about the only purpose of it. It is neither a client nor a server, just a serialization helper tool.

Comment: Isn't it a transport since it inherits `TTransport`?

Comment: Yes it is, but it only "transports" the bits into a binary form. What you do with that buffer is up to you. There are use cases where the real transport to a target is made by some other means, e.g. message brokers/bus systems, any kind of asynchronous message transfer, etc. Having only raw bytes in such a case often comes quite handy. At the end, Thrift is defined as "RPC and serialization framework"